# Return Temporary Spark SQL Table in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

First I convert a CSV file to a Spark DataFrame using

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("/usr/people.csv")
```

after that type df and return I can see

```
res30: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: string, gender: string, deptID: string, salary: string]
```

Then I use `df.registerTempTable("people")` to convert df to a Spark SQL table.

But after that when I do `people` Instead got type table, I got

```
<console>:33: error: not found: value people
```

Is it because people is a temporary table?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you register an temp table using the registerTempTable command you used, it will be available inside your SQLContext.

This means that the following is incorrect and will give you the error you are getting :

```
scala> people.show
<console>:33: error: not found: value people
```

To use the temp table, you'll need to call it with your sqlContext. Example :

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from people")
```

**Note :** `df.registerTempTable("df")` will register a temporary table with name `df` correspond to the DataFrame `df` you apply the method on.

So persisting on df wont persist the table but the DataFrame, even thought the SQLContext will be using that DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is right for Zeppelin too. If you want to run println to see data, you have to send it back to the driver to see output.

```
val querystrings = sqlContext.sql("select visitorDMA, 
        visitorIpAddress, visitorState, allRequestKV
    from {redacted} 
    limit 1000")

querystrings.collect.foreach(entry => {
    print(entry.getString(3).toString() + "\n")
})
```